# Is it possible to "unjam" a tire without having it repaired?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

It's very irritating having a jammed tire after smashing into something, and even having 100% armour doesn't prevent it from happening. Are there any DIY tactics you can perform on the side of the road (or while in the car) to "unjam" the tire without having to drive to a repair shop to get it repaired? Would another collision fix it?

(Note - if possible can an answer account for bulletproof tires too)

Comment: Does shooting the tire count?

Comment: (Note - if possible can an answer account for bulletproof tires too) - so while it can - it's not really ideal.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, no.

If the axle jams there is not a way to fix it apart from repairing the vehicle. Blowing out the tire via fire, firearms, or continuing to drive with the jammed wheel will regain some speed at the cost of maneuverability - but not back to it's pre-jam state.

If this happens your best options are to look for a repair shop or replacement vehicle if playing in the open world, or a repair pickup/powerup if playing in a GTA Online race.